# Is is possible to set BufferSize in FileStream?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I need to write large data into disk, so I use `FileStream.openAsync()`:

```
this.file_stream = new FileStream();
this.file_stream.openAsync(fl, FileMode.WRITE);

//Write large get from database
while(i < 10240000) {
    this.file_stream.write(bigDatas)
    i = i + 1;
}
```

And then, the app killed by Linux kenkel (message copy from 'dmesg'):

> Killed process 4267 (MyFlex) total-vm:1282708kB, anon-rss:863176kB, file-rss:756kB

So, is there any way to set buffer size in FileStream?

Comment: This might be useful, even though it concerns reading not writing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321951/as3-working-with-arbitrarily-large-files

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute a cycle 10 millions of times.

The problem is not the buffer of the FileStream. Say thanks to Linux that stop the execution of your App and avoid that your system blow up.

You need to save one file and when the file is saved, go for the next, look at the code, the "writeFile" function wait for the CLOSE event to execute itself again.

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.events.Event;

var file:File;
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();

stream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, writeFile);

var cont:uint = 0;
//---I do not think that you need to run a code 10 million times (This code will save the file 10 times)
var total:uint = 10;

//---Write file in the Desktop in the folder "test"
function writeFile(evt:Event = null){

    cont++;

    if(cont == total + 1) {

        stream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, writeFile);

        trace("finish");

    }else{

        trace("write file number " + cont);

        file = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("test/data" + cont);

        stream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);

        stream.writeByte(0xFF);

        stream.close();

    }

}

//---Execute the function for first time
writeFile();
```